# NSPopUpButton: NSPopUpButtonCell deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspopupbutton, macos-mojave

The [documentation for NSPopUpButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopupbutton?changes=latest_minor&language=objc) states:

> An NSPopUpButton object uses an NSPopUpButtonCell object to implement its user interface.

I derived a new class from `NSPopUpButtonCell` which implements `drawBorderAndBackgroundWithFrame:inView:` to achieve custom drawing. In addition, I derived a new class from `NSPopUpButton` and use `cellClass` to use my derived class for it. (i.e. I am not working via interface builder.)

With the advent of macOS 10.14 beta however, this routine is not called anymore, and I observe the "normal" (i.e. non-customized) drawing.

Thanks to [@Marc T.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51184255/255688), I (think I) was able to localize the problem to the fact that the cell apparently calls `drawBorderAndBackgroundWithFrame:inView:` only if `drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:` is implemented in the derived cell.

I could not find solid documentation on this. Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there would be such a change in macOS 10.14 I assume Apple would have announced this on WWDC 2018. A quick check in Interface Builder showed me that nothing has changed so far. Creating a subclass of NSPopUpButtonCell to use it as the class for the popup button cell is still working as expected. 
What I have to mention is that drawBorderAndBackground is only called if drawInterior is implemented as well. Since I was never using drawBorderAndBackground  before, I can not say if this is a change from previous versions to 10.14 or not.

```
class Cell: NSPopUpButtonCell {

override func drawInterior(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
    super.drawInterior(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    print("drawInterior")
}

override func drawBorderAndBackground(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
    super.drawBorderAndBackground(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    print("drawBorderAndBackground")
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you are right that I need to implement `drawInterior` in my derived class. How did you find out about this? Trial-and-error? Can you point me to some documentation?

Comment: @phimuemue Intuitively, I am programming Cocoa now for over 10 years :-)

Comment: @Mark T Thank you. Slightly off-topic: I still find it uncommon to check whether a derived class implements `MethodA` to decide whether we call `MethodB`. Do you know other examples where Cocoa does that kind of check?

Comment: @phimuemue I don't remember exactly when I got the problems but many times it was related to Controls, drawing and events.